# Simple selenium test failing when using AssertEqual function

Tags: python, selenium, variables, testing

My whole script works until the last 2 lines where it fails.

```
    # Your shopping cart is empty banner
    emptyBanner = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/p").text
    self.assertEqual(emptyBanner, "Your shopping cart is empty.", "The basket is not empty")
```

when stepping through the code while debugging, I can see a variable 'emptyBanner' of type String is created and 'Your shopping cart is empty.' is stored within it.

Then on the last line comparing the variable and then the string, it fails.

On the exception error, the expected result is blank, I don't understand where the string stored in the variable went?

```
Ran 1 test in 14.127s

FAILED (failures=1)

The basket is not empty
Your shopping cart is empty. != 

Expected :
Actual   :Your shopping cart is empty.
```

I'm at a complete loss.

Here's the full code (im very new to coding/selenium):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
  def testShoppingCart(self):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php")
    driver.maximize_window()

    actions = ActionChains(driver)

    # locators for Women and Summer Dresses in Nav Menu
    Women = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/header/div[3]/div/div/div[6]/ul/li[1]/a")
    summerDresses = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "/html/body/div/div[1]/header/div[3]/div/div/div[6]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[3]/a")

    # select Summer Dresses from Nav Menu
    actions.move_to_element(Women).move_to_element(summerDresses).click().perform()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[1]").click() #click dress
    driver.find_element_by_id("add_to_cart").click() #add dress to cart
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/header/div[3]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/a").click() #click proceed to checkout button

    #checkout
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/p").is_displayed() #check to see if dress is in checkout
    trashIcon = driver.find_element_by_class_name("icon-trash")
    trashIcon.is_displayed() #check to see if delete button is displayed
    trashIcon.click() #click delete icon
    
    # Your shopping cart is empty banner
    emptyBanner = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/p").text
    self.assertEqual(emptyBanner, "Your shopping cart is empty.", "The basket is not empty")



   if __name__ == '__main__':
       unittest.main()
```

Comment: Print out `emptyBanner ` if it does not equal "Your shopping cart is empty." or "The basket is not empty" the test will fail.  Please show us the `assertEqual` function. I can only guess at what is happening until we know what is in that function.

Comment: I've stepped through the code up until where I use a locator to store the .text value inside the variable 'emptyBanner' [screenshot](https://gyazo.com/ce234628584cc8184c04e29ed29bcc77)  as you can see the string 'Your shopping cart is empty' is stored in the variable

On the next line I print(emptyBanner) and can see it is printed in the console [screenshot](https://gyazo.com/14812df362cc65d998582968af7e6c87)

and then finally the assert Statement is where it breaks. 

[assert function](https://gyazo.com/74d1c482235fa74ad53eda739a058b54?token=65d028b351cadba73096e68c986ac0c5)

Comment: the screen shot shows what parameters the `assertEqual` function takes in but not what is does with the function inputs.

Comment: Are you sure you clicked on the right element on this one /html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[1] .